# Tensorflow 1.8, tf.keras gives different result in DCGAN from Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to get back into the latest developments of TensorFlow and Keras.
I've tried to read up on whether using tf.keras or keras and I got the impression that when using TF as backend,it should't matter much, even though tf.keras has a different codebase than keras.

However, using Colaboratory with GPU backend, I tried to follow https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/dcgan/dcgan.py

First using tf.keras. I get lot's of warnings like:

```python
WARNING:tensorflow:Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable weights, did you set `model.trainable` without calling `model.compile` after ?
950 [D loss: 0.000024, acc.: 100.00%] [G loss: 0.000006]
```

( I did follow the discussion here: see https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8585)

The accuracy is 100% and the losses are very small, however, when I used the trained model to generate and visualise pictures I only get a washed-out gray picture without any structure after 1000 iterations. Running longer doesn't improve things.

If I use "native" keras by changing the import statements, I get the warning only once

```python
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:975: UserWarning: Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable weights, did you set `model.trainable` without calling `model.compile` after ?
  'Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable'
0 [D loss: 1.239847, acc.: 39.06%] [G loss: 0.439355]
50 [D loss: 0.746472, acc.: 58.59%] [G loss: 1.010316]
...
950 [D loss: 0.672316, acc.: 58.59%] [G loss: 0.916285]
```

Note how the accuracy remains at roughly 60% and the losses around 1 compared to tf.keras. Even after 1000 iterations (same as above) I can generate reasonable numbers, not great perhaps but mostly recognizeable.

Am I missing something obvious (in this case, my apologies)? Or is it not a good idea to use tf.keras?

I've made a copy of my notebook here:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SKYDidvwkbQBH4cuT1YXSO_KUNM_OagJ

and pasted the code below. Many thanks in advance

```python
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import tensorflow as tf

#Keras from TensorFlow
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation, Dropout, LeakyReLU, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Flatten, Reshape, ZeroPadding2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Adam

#pure keras
#from keras.datasets import mnist
#from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape, Flatten, Dropout
#from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, ZeroPadding2D
#from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
#from keras.layers.convolutional import UpSampling2D, Conv2D
#from keras.models import Sequential, Model
#from keras.optimizers import Adam


from tensorflow.python.keras.datasets import mnist
print("all modules imported")

##
## DATA
## (already as 28x28 pix 2D numpy array)
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()


plt.clf()
plt.imshow(x_train[0],cmap='gray',interpolation='none')
plt.title("Label: {}".format(y_train[0]))

def discriminator():
  model = Sequential()

  model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, input_shape=(28,28,1), padding="same"))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
  model.add(Dropout(0.25))
  model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
  model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0,1),(0,1))))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
  model.add(Dropout(0.25))
  model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
  model.add(Dropout(0.25))
  model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="same"))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
  model.add(Dropout(0.25))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

  #model.summary()

  img = Input(shape=(28,28,1))
  out = model(img)
  return Model(img, out)
​
def generator():
  model = Sequential()

  model.add(Dense(128 * 7 * 7, activation="relu", input_dim=100))
  model.add(Reshape((7, 7, 128)))
  model.add(UpSampling2D())
  model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
  model.add(Activation("relu"))
  model.add(UpSampling2D())
  model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
  model.add(Activation("relu"))
  model.add(Conv2D(1, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
  model.add(Activation("tanh"))

  #model.summary()

  noise = Input(shape=(100,))
  out = model(noise)
  return Model(noise,out)

optimizer = Adam(0.0002, 0.5)

discr_ = discriminator()
discr_.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['accuracy'] )
n_disc_trainable = len(discr_.trainable_weights)


# generator takes noise and generates images
gen_ = generator()
n_gen_trainable = len(gen_.trainable_weights)

z = Input(shape=(100,))
img = gen_(z)

#combined model - only train generator
discr_.trainable = False

valid_image = discr_(img)
combined_model = Model(z,valid_image)
combined_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)

#check number of trainable weights, both numbers should be the same
#see https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8585
ok_discr = False
ok_combined = False
n_discr_collected = len(discr_._collected_trainable_weights)
print("Discriminator collected trainable weights {}, set trainable weights {}".format(n_discr_collected, n_disc_trainable))
if n_discr_collected == n_disc_trainable:
  print("Disriminator weights OK")
  ok_discr = True
n_combined = len(combined_model._collected_trainable_weights)
print("Combined collected trainable weights {}, set trainable weights {}".format(n_combined, n_gen_trainable))
if n_combined == n_gen_trainable:
  print("Combined Model weights OK")
  ok_combined = True
if ok_discr and ok_combined:
  print("All weights OK, ignore warnings about model.compile / trainable")

batch_size = 64

# Rescale -1 to 1 --?
x_train = x_train / 127.5 - 1.

# dataset is in shape (28,28) but require (28,28,1) - last digit is #channels
x2 = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=3)

# Adversarial ground truths
valid = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
fake = np.zeros((batch_size, 1))

for epoch in range(1000):
  ##
  ## train discriminator
  ##

  # Select a random half of images
  idx = np.random.randint(0, x2.shape[0], batch_size)
  imgs = x2[idx]

  # Sample noise and generate a batch of new images
  noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, 100))
  gen_imgs = gen_.predict(noise)

  # Train the discriminator (real classified as ones and generated as zeros)
  d_loss_real = discr_.train_on_batch(imgs, valid)
  d_loss_fake = discr_.train_on_batch(gen_imgs, fake)
  d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)

  ##
  ## train generator
  ##

  # Train the generator (wants discriminator to mistake images as real)
  g_loss = combined_model.train_on_batch(noise, valid)

  # Plot the progress
  if epoch % 50 == 0:
    print ("%d [D loss: %f, acc.: %.2f%%] [G loss: %f]" % (epoch, d_loss[0], 100*d_loss[1], g_loss))
```